# Understanding admin links

Tags: adminhtml

Im try to make a Magento Admin area module but have got stuck with a link issue.

So far I have my required option in the menu bar but my problem comes when I click the link, I get a 404 error, I expected a grid. I am following a tutorial from [excellencemagentoblog](http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/admin-part1-series-magento-admin-forms-grids-controllers-tabs#more-657).

I understand that the action node  within the children node of the tree is the link and I have followed my file path to create what I expected would be the correct link, but that failes and I cannot work out why?

My code is

excellence/employee/adminHtml.xml

```
<config>
<menu><!--action node, URL of admin controller-->
    <employee module="employee">
        <title>Employee</title>
        <sort_order>90</sort_order>
        <children>
            <items module="employee"><!--adds menu item-->
                <title>Manage Employees</title>
                <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                <action>employee/adminhtml_employee</action><!--Link-->
            </items>
        </children>
    </employee>
</menu>
<acl>
    <resources>
        <all>
            <title>Allow Everthing</title>
        </all>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <excellence_employee>
                    <title>Employee Module</title>
                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                </excellence_employee>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
<layout>
    <updates>
        <employee>
            <file>employee.xml</file>
        </employee>
    </updates>
</layout>
</config>
```

Excellence/Employee/controllers/AdminHtml/EmployeeController.php

```
class Excellence_Employee_Adminhtml_EmployeeController
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

I have tried logging out and back in again, but I still get the 404. What have i do wrong?

When I click the link the address is

```
http://magentodevtest.local/index.php/employee/adminhtml_employee/index/key/45435404fsd453453
```

I have added an image of my file structure, looking at the address bar, my understanding of how files are accessed says it should work (i obviously misunderstand something)[image: Img of the file structure]

===EDIT===

I have cache disabled

My config.xml is as follows

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Excellence_Employee>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Excellence_Employee>
</modules>
<global>
    <blocks>
        <employee>
            <class>Excellence_Employee_Block</class>
        </employee>
    </blocks>
    <models>
        <employee>
            <class>Excellence_Employee_Model</class>
        </employee>
    </models>
    <helpers>
        <employee>
            <class>Excellence_Employee_Helper</class>
        </employee>
    </helpers>
</global>
</config>
```

Comment: First try clearing the cache. If nothing happens post the contents of `config.xml` in the question. Also...small tip: rename `adminHtml.xml` to `adminhtml.xml`. You will have problems if you don't on other OS.

Comment: @Marius, Please see my edit. I have changed adminHtml.xml as you suggested

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I suspected you are missing the `routers` in your `config.xml`. Add this node under the `<global>` node:

```
<admin>
    <routers>
       <employee>
           <use>admin</use>
           <args>
               <module>Excellence_Employee</module>
               <frontName>employee</frontName>
           </args>
       </employee>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Or better yet. a more elegant solution is to have your module have the path start with `admin` like all the admin modules. For this, instead of the code above add this:

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Excellence_Employee before="Mage_Adminhtml">Excellence_Employee_Adminhtml</Excellence_Employee>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

After adding this your module admin url should look like this `admin/employee/index`.
And you should change the `<action>` in your menu to

```
<action>adminhtml/employee</action>
```

I recommend the second option. It's nicer and has some advantages if you want to use for example Varnish in front of your server. It's easier to configure.

**[EDIT]**
The first solution does not work anymore, in versions 1.9.2+ and presents a security risk for versions previous to that.

Comment: Thankyou for your help. I have added the admin node to the global node and changed the action node. My url like like what you suggested, but I am still getting a 404, do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: maybe clear the cache.  Or you can check this for suggestions http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store

Comment: Thnks for that link. It hasnt covered what I was looking for. I know its a simple error somewhere in my config. i will keep looking

Comment: Thanks to Marius I was able to work through my remaining problems and work out that I had deleted the `</global>` node when I added his solution